# How do I represent an OLS regression model as a mathematical equation?

Tags: regression, least-squares

I have created an OLS regression model as part a pre-test/post-test experimental design with a single factor (group membership).

In order to investigate the interaction between pre-test and group membership, I created the following OLS model in python (using the `statsmodels` package):

`post ~ pre*group`

The output is:

[image]

I would like to express the model as an equation. Am I right in thinking that the equation is:

$y = b_0+ b_1 x_1+ b_2 x_2 + b_3 x_1 x_2$

Where $y$ is the post-test, $x_1$ is the pre-test, $x_2$ is the dummy variable and $b_n$ are the coefficients?

Thanks.

Comment: There are some technical issues like writing hats on the estimates, giving an expected value of $y$, or writing an error term, but you’ve got the gist, yes!

Comment: @Dave Thanks. Could you possibly post an answer with the correct notion?

Comment: See [these posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=write+regression+equation+-logistic+is%3Aquestion).